# Check if arp table contains certain MAC address

Tags: shell, grep

I want to build a .sh script for a tomatousb router that would be launched once a minute and send requests to telegrambot api once the certain mac address is added or removed from the router's arp table. 
I want to store the last state (if the mac address was found) in the env variable, but I have no clue how to check for the address.
I would normally do

```
if [(arp -a | grep aabbccdd)!=null] then
  /usr/bin/wget https://api.telegram.org/... --no-check-certificate
```

but that doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `arp -a | egrep -o '(\w{1,2}:){5}\w{1,2}'` returns all the available MAC addresses for me, using Bash 3.2 on a MacOS (10.13) system.

Comment: thanks! that worke just fine!

Comment: sure, if i don't forget)

Answer (score 0):

`arp -a | egrep -o '(\w{1,2}:){5}\w{1,2}'` will return all the available MAC addresses.